# Why is this not a counter example to the completeness of the supremum norm on the space of continuous functions defined on compact intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

On the one hand, I am aware of the proofs concerning the completeness of said function space under the supremum norm. On the other hand, I encountered a sequence of functions that - to my understanding - contradicts the completeness mentioned above. Obviously, there has to be a flaw in my reasoning. However, I can’t find it and therefore ask for your help!

Consider the sequence of functions in the space of continuous functions defined on compact intervals:
$f_n(x)=x^n$ with $x \in [0,1]$.
Clearly, the limit value $f(x) := \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ of this sequence is $0$ for $x \in [0,1)$ and $1$ for $x=1$. Thus, $f(x)$ is not continuous on the interval $[0,1]$, in particular, the sequence of functions does not converge point-wise inside the space of continuous functions.

Non point-wise convergence of the limit implies non uniform convergence of the limit, because uniform convergence implies point-wise convergence.

Uniform convergence is equivalent to saying that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\limits_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)-f_n(x)| \to 0$. This is equivalent to saying the sequence of functions is a Cauchy sequence.

The sequence does not uniformly converge and hence the sequence is not a Cauchy sequence. Cauchy sequences have to imply point-wise convergence of the sequence for the defined norm - in this case the supremum norm - to be complete on the space of continuous function on a compact interval. Since the sequence possesses neither convergence one could argue it doesn’t contradict the the function spaces‘ completeness.

However, with a different approach, I come to a different answer. By checking for the uniform convergence of the sequence, the following result arises : $\lim_{n\to\infty} |f(1)-f_n(1)| = |1-1| =0$. The case for $x \in [0,1)$ is trivial. So, the sequence is a Cauchy sequence. But because the limit value is not included, the sequence does not convergence point-wise. This would be a contradiction.

Where is my false logic?

Thanks a lot for answering in advance!

Comment: $(f_n)$ is pointwise convergent, but not uniformly on $[0, 1]$. Where exactly do you see a contradiction?

Comment: The sequence $f_n$ is not Cauchy.

Comment: Try to write down the "trivial" case of $x \in [0,1)$ and you'll see the flaw in your reasoning.

Comment: There is no limit function that is continuous.

Comment: Nothing is so trivial that it is trivial. The use of the word "trivial" indicates the lack of a logical argument.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} |f(1)-f_n(1)| = |1-1| =0$ is simply another way of saying that $f_n(1) \to f(1)$. I.e., that $f_n \to f$ pointwise **at** $1$. This is different from $f_n \to f$ uniformly (which is a terminology not even defined at a single point).